# React build doesn't work with axios proxy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

My problem is:

I've build a MERN stack app. I have nodejs app connected to mongodb atlas deployed on VM in GCP. Everything works great and this VM serves the request on http://35.240.91.193:5000. You may see it going to http://35.240.91.193:5000/api/profile.

My client app is build with React and creates connection to nodejs app through the axios calls.
It works through the "proxy" properties set in package.json as {"proxy": "http://35.240.91.193:5000"}. When I run client app in dev mode (npm start) everything works great, but when I run npm run build and deploy the build package with nginx (locally or remotely) connection requests do not work.
Through the network tab in dev tools I see the request are not going through the proxy but as "http://client_host/api/profile" but it should be "http://35.240.91.193:5000/api/profile".

Here is the client code
https://github.com/GeorgeFalkovich/csc_fe

Answer (score 1):

The proxy in the `package.json` only works in dev mode, in production it is assumed that the front end and the api server live on the same server, you can fix this by adding a base  URL via axios like this

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development") {
    axios.defaults.baseURL = 'BASE URL TO YOUR API';
}
```

Put this code before any axios requests are made.

Comment: Hi Shmili and thank you for the answer. While your answer shows me the reason of the fault my app is still does not work. After putting axios.defaults.baseURL it show that it makes right requests but CORS error still blocks all my axios request in build production. Any idea how can I treat it without browser special plugins but on production environment? I have to create one single VM nodejs-mongodb and 3 client react VMs. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The issue was resolved by adding

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development") {
    axios.defaults.baseURL = 'BASE URL TO YOUR API';
}
```

to my client app before any axios request was called

and adding middleware(npm install) cors to my nodejs server file

```
app.use(cors());
```